# How to create a single space in css between a sentence and a photo on my wordpress site?

Tags: css, spacing

How do I create a single space in css between a sentence and a photo on my wordpress site? I tried wrapping my sentence with the following code: `<span style="font-size: 0.8em; line-height: 75%;">blahblahblah</span>` but this did not do work.

Edit:
My apologies for the late response. I am just trying to include a Flickr link at the bottom of my photo to attribute/credit the photographer - but I would like to have a single space between the photo and the attribute/credit link. Below is the code for what I currently have at the top of my blog post:

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-68 alignnone" title="What Causes Eczema" src="http://eczemafreedomacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/what_causes_eczema.jpg" alt="What Causes Eczema" width="500" height="500" /><span style="font-size: 0.8em;">(Photo: <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/helga/3952984450/" target="_blank">Helga Weber</a>)</span>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the HTML you are using for the image and text?

Comment: show some working example to get exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish without seeing your HTML, but assuming the simplest case this should work.

First ad an id attribute to your image tag. It can by any id value as long as it doesn't duplicate the id of another element and matches what you have in the style code.

```
<img id="yourImageID"....>
```

Add a style element to your document (usually inside the head element), or add this CSS markup to an existing style element. You can also insert the inner part into any CSS file linked to by your document. Read [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) for more on where to put this.

```
#yourImageID {
    margin: 1em;
}
```

BTW: It is generally not a good practice to put styles inline on your elements. Put them in a separate `<style>` element in your document.

Comment: I am sorry but I am terrible at css. Can you please let me know where to insert it into my code that I posted in my original post. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: I put some more detail in the answer, hopefully it will help. If you are going to be doing much HTML work, you really need to know how to associate styles without putting them directly on elements.

Comment: Thanks...this is still quite confusing for me. I will probably end up going to Elance to pay someone to walk me through it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hang in there. It isn't so bad with a little practice. SO is here to help when you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell with no original HTML showing, but maybe all you need to do is add `&nbsp;` to the end of your sentence.

If that doesn't work, tell us more about what you're trying to do. The code you added doesn't attempt to add a space, so it could be I'm confused.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have clarified what I'm trying to do

Comment: @JackStevens Well, then my solution should read to add `&nbsp;` to the _beginning_ of your sentence. Or you can use JohnFx's solution...

Comment: I tried putting &nbsp; to the beginning but it did not work. I am sorry but I am terrible at css. Can you please let me know where to insert it into my code that I posted in my original post. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: In your example, where you have `<span style="font-size: 0.8em;">(Photo: ...` you can put an nbsp in, or even a normal space, just before the opening parenthesis: `<span style="font-size: 0.8em;"> (Photo: ...`